# How to read variables from csv file based on context

Tags: csv, csvsimple

I'm trying to read two variables from a csv file.

```
function,value
1. pos,some text
2. pos,some other text
```

This runs before `\begin{document}` and I wan't the value of `1. pos` in `\firstvar` and the value of `2. pos` in `\secondvar`.
**Edit:** By `value` I mean the `value`-column, not the string `1. pos` itself.

```tex
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\newcommand{\firstvar}{tmpvalone}
\newcommand{\secondvar}{tmpvaltwo}
\csvreader[head to column names]{file.csv}{}%
{
    \ifstrequal{\function}{1. pos}
    {\renewcommand{\firstvar}{\value}}
    {
        \ifstrequal{\function}{2. pos}
        {\renewcommand{\secondvar}{\value}}
        {}
    }
}
```

Currently, there are two problems:

1. `\ifstrequal` *doesn't work*. I know it has something to do with the expansion of the commands, but I couldn't get it to work, even with `\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter`.
2. Even if the comparison would work, the `\renewcommand` would be empty. I tested this, by using `\ifnumequal{\thecsvrow}{x}` instead of `\ifstrequal`.

I feel like, I'm really close, but I don't really understand what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{630556.csv}
function,value
1. pos,some text
2. pos,some other text
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\firstvar}{tmpvalone}
\newcommand{\secondvar}{tmpvaltwo}

\csvreader[head to column names]{630556.csv}{}{
  \ifcsvstrequal{\function}{1. pos}{ \edef\firstvar{\value} } { }
  \ifcsvstrequal{\function}{2. pos}{ \edef\secondvar{\value} }{ }
}

\firstvar \quad \secondvar

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, wow. Thx. I must have overlooked `\ifcsvstrequal` when reading the docs of `csvsimple` earlier.

Answer (score 3):

Here, I use facilities of the `readarray` package, as an alternative.  EDITED answer.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{file.csv}
function,value
1. pos,some text
2. pos,some other text
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray,forloop}
\newcounter{loopindex}
\readarraysepchar{,}
\readdef{file.csv}\filedef
\readarray*\filedef\var[-,2]
\def\onepos{1. pos}
\def\twopos{2. pos}
\forloop{loopindex}{2}{\value{loopindex}<\numexpr\varROWS+1}{
  \arraytomacro\var[\theloopindex,1]\tmp
  \ifx\tmp\onepos\xdef\firstvar{\var[\theloopindex,2]}\fi
  \ifx\tmp\twopos\xdef\secondvar{\var[\theloopindex,2]}\fi
}
\begin{document}
``\firstvar'' and ``\secondvar''
\end{document}
```

[image]

Furthermore, the 2-D array `\var` contains all the bits of the file, `\var[3,2]` contains `some other text`, while `\var[1,1]` contains `function`, and so on.

Comment: I think I made it not clear enough, that I need to select `some text` based on the row, where `1. pos` is, and `some other text` based on `2. pos`. That's the only reason why I'm trying to use `\ifstrequal`.

Comment: @Darkproduct It is still not clear to me what syntax you hope to use to achieve what resulting string.

Comment: I'm generating several forms and I need to change the footer on one single source of truth, because changing this in all documents is tidies. For convenience, I wont to read those from a csv, so this can be changed in the future, from someone who doesn't know much about latex. This means, that the order of the values in the csv file could change.

Comment: @Darkproduct Please see my edit, if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, that's perfect. +1 I'll still keep the accepted answer, because it was earlier and - for me at least - it is easier to understand and I already use `csvsimple` in some other parts anyway.